# Sometimes install4j launcher does not start

Tags: windows, install4j

We have a small problem. Our install4j launcher does not always launch the application in the first try, but when trying a second, or sometimes after a third try, it starts. Sometimes it starts at first try. I have no idea why it behaves like this.

I've started the launcher with log output and the log is written. In case, that the application does not launch, the last lines in the log file are:

> [3:282] vmoption 14: -Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\HMS.install4j\i4jruntime.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\HMS.\gdt-starter.jar

> [3:289] used stack size 0

> [3:297] Creating JVM

Also there is no error (not shown when starting the launcher or in the log file)

We use install4j 10.0.4 and JRE 1.8.0_341 as 32bit (this is neccessary unfortunately). I've reproduced the problem on Windows 11, but it also occurs in older Windows versions.

Can someone provide help? The launcher should start the application every time and not only sometimes.

Comment: Isn't install4j a commercial product? So you should have product support by the company who sells it. What do they think about your problem?

Comment: Did you receive my reply to the support request that you sent to us?

Comment: @Robert Yes, that is correct, but we also offer support on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @IngoKegel no, I didn't receive the response. that's why I asked here.

Comment: OK, I see that your email address was wrong for your previous ticket, I've just answered your current ticket.

Answer (score 0):

From the log file, this problem is due to a too high -Xmx value for a 32-Bit application. The effectively obtainable maximum heap size is reduced to the address space layout randomization, and the error occurs sporadically. For more than 800 MB of maximum heap, a 64-bit JVM should be used.